# How do I use an user access token to with the Facebook graph api? (PHP)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I don't have any issue getting my access token:

```
$accessToken = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$appID&client_secret=$appSecret&grant_type=client_credentials");
```

But I seem to be missing part of the core concept of how to use it. For example, when I request:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/statuses?access_token=$accessToken");
```

(And yeah, I'm stripping out the "access_token=" part in between the two lines, the URL is good)

I get this back:

```
{
   "error": {
  "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 102
  }
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to what I'm missing here. I know with people you need them to authorize it, but this is just a page with public statuses.

Answer (score 3):

That's an app access token you're using - to make calls on behalf of a user you need them to authorise your app using the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flows in the documentation

An app access token (which you get from the client_credentials call above) should give you completely public posts, but many pages are demographically restricted, or the posts themselves are targeted only at certain countries, in which case you need a user access token to retrieve them

Comment: So in this specific case, why is it that cocacola doesn't work? Since Facebook uses it in an code example I would have to assume everything is public or they would have chosen a different "page". To be more specific I'm actually doing this for two clients and they both have pages - this method works on one and not the other. They are restaurants located in the same city so I don't think the demographic issue is coming into play here.

Comment: Cocacola works, but cocacola/statuses does not, that connection always needs an access token - no idea why your pages don't work but presumably one of them is restricted by age or location